# Android - Input Text within app doesn't work

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

I'm trying to input text into the current running application (not my own) using the adb input text method, this works if I run it from the command prompt such as 'adb input text "Android" and also if I run it from terminal emulator.  However the below code run successfully but produces no output on the screen.. I have also tried various other methods to run shell commands which have also not failed but not output any text..
Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
try {
            //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input text \":\"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inject text into an android app the injector must have

```
   android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS
```

permission, so it must be a system app.

Your Runtime.getRuntime().exec has not this permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still no luck nothing is output.  I also tried with an EditText in my application and it works fine..  I can run it from terminal for any app too..

Answer (score 0):

If you run your command from Native executable, it works fine.
Build a NDK binary and execute:

```
char * command = "input text hello%sworld\0";
system( command );//fork and exec input text ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use :
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shell input text");`